# What is the difference between orphaned and runtime only pods in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

The documentation to the [kubernetes metrics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/instrumentation/metrics/) says:

> Number of pods the kubelet is actually running, broken down by lifecycle phase, whether the pod is desired, orphaned, or runtime only (also orphaned), and whether the pod is static. An orphaned pod has been removed from local configuration or force deleted in the API and consumes resources that are not otherwise visible.

What is the difference between orphaned and runtime only pods in kubernetes? Do I understand correctly that runtime only pods also include orphaned pods?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Context of orphaned pods meaning that they are no longer associated with any deployment or ReplicaSet,  a Runtime-only pods would fall on that same description as long as they are not part of any desired state. So in short a Runtime-only pod would be the same as Orphaned pods if those conditions are met.

Comment: Where I can found more information about this topic? What means "no longer associated"? Pods with controller field set, but no such controller found?

Comment: You can check this documentation for more details. [1]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/garbage-collection/#orphaned-dependents

Comment: Thank you! One more question: where can I find information about runtime-only pods (especially what means: "as long as they are not part of any desired state")?